# Display all hamiltonian cycles or circuits in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory, undirected-graph, hamiltonian-cycle

I found this algorithm that shows me just one hamiltonian cycle but I need to print all hamiltonian cycles in an undirected graph.

Here's the code that I tried to use: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hamiltonian-cycle-backtracking-6/

Could someone help me with the implementation?
In addition, this code show me all hamiltonian path:
http://www.techiedelight.com/print-all-hamiltonian-path-present-in-a-graph/

Comment: What have tried coding so far?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vR3pm-zOQx09wejPOoTk-u7ZQQTpa7Ljeh0_pjQDfFCgKEGDKF6Mvu45V4O6xlPmPh1EtgLgOpJA41U/pub

This algorithm show me just one of them:
i.e:
Solution Exists: Following is one Hamiltonian Cycle
 0  1  2  3  4  0